# Ramjet: How to make element appear and reappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to follow the code for ramjet  http://www.rich-harris.co.uk/ramjet/, but I can't get element a to disappear while moving into b.  I also get --Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined--.  Element a does move, though.  How can I get a to turn into b, as shown on the page.

Script.js

```
$(document).ready( function() {
// set the stage so ramjet copies the right styles...
b.classList.remove('hidden');

ramjet.transform( a, b, {
  done: function () {
    // this function is called as soon as the transition completes
    b.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
});

// ...then hide the original elements for the duration of the transition
a.classList.add('hidden');
b.classList.add('hidden');
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./ramjet.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="back">
       <div id="a"></div>
       <div id="b" class="hidden"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

stylesheet.css

```
.back {
    float: left;
    width: 790px;
    height: 525px;    
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #BCD2EE
}

#a {
    margin: 200px 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 175px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #666699;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#b {
    margin: 200px 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 175px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the script in my head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ramjet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
// set the stage so ramjet copies the right styles...
b.classList.remove('hidden');

ramjet.transform( a, b, {
  done: function () {
    // this function is called as soon as the transition completes
    b.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
});

// ...then hide the original elements for the duration of the transition
a.classList.add('hidden');
b.classList.add('hidden');
});
</script>
```

no change in css
the code works fine. the div b got hide and div a acquire the property of b.

i think the problem is in your script path the you define in your docs head section. check your path.

Comment: check that your path of ramjet.js and script.js file is correct. because your path is like this <script type="text/javascript" src="./ramjet.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>. why are you writning ./ in front of it. put all your your file in same folder and then check. it will works.

Comment: If ramjet works and jquery works even a little bit, it should mean that it's pointing correctly.. but i went ahead and changed it, to test, but it still does the same thing..

Comment: check your script path bro

Comment: cause my script works fine. i put all file ( index.php and script.js and ramjet.js ) in same folder name "test"

Comment: ramjet.js also works  fine. if ypu think that your problem is in ramjet.js then try save the js code again.

Comment: check what you coded and check the ramjet webpage... they do not look the same at all

Comment: this is the error you get if ramjet was wrong:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
script.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: ramjet is not defined

---- that's not the original error

Comment: yes. the problem is in your ramjet.js file. try copy the content again of ramjet.js.

Comment: I copied your code as-is, and downloaded the jquery instead of using a cdn link, it is still the same.  The only think I changed was adding a css link to the head code to make the div's show up.  Anyway the outcome is the same.  you can see the transition, but '#a' and '#b' stay in the same place.  I also still get that ""Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined"" error in the end.

Comment: I guess it's my chrome browser, I stopped being stubborn and switched to Firefox and it worked perfectly... not sure why chrome gives the TypeError and firefox works just fine... Thanks

Comment: @mc805 ur welcome bro. and yes, chrome has it's own issues with custom js.

Answer (score 1):

[image: that's my div ' a ']

before changing my div a looks like this. after the DOM get loads it turns and acquire the property of div b as red:
[image: after DOM load]

Comment: what's your exact html and your exact script.js?